# Dynamic listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, dynamic

I'm new to Flutter, but I'm trying to make an app with a `ListView`. The `ListView` is a list of exercises, within each exercise the number of sets can be added. The problem comes when i press the button add exercise. The above exercise with sets is just copied. I would like a new exercise tab with 0 sets. Below the code can be found.

Here is a picture of the list.

[image: First exercise]

[image: Second exercise (seems to be a copy of above)]

```
final decoratedField = InputDecoration(
    filled: false,
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
    ),
    hintText: "null",
  );
```

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          titleSection,
          // ignore: unnecessary_new
          new TextField(
            controller: eCtrl,
            onSubmitted: (text) {
              litems.add(text);
              eCtrl.clear();
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
          Expanded(
              // ignore: unnecessary_new
              child: new ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: litems.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
                    return Card(
                        child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: ExpansionTile(
                              initiallyExpanded: true,
                              title: Text(
                                litems[Index],
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(child: Text(" ")),
                                  //Expanded(child: Text("data")),
                                  //Expanded(child: Text("data")),
                                  //Expanded(child: Text("data")),
                                ],
                              ),
                              // ignore: sort_child_properties_last
                              children: <Widget>[
                                ListView.builder(
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    itemCount: sets.length,
                                    itemBuilder:
                                        (BuildContext context, int Index1) {
                                      return Dismissible(
                                          key: UniqueKey(),

                                          // only allows the user swipe from right to left
                                          direction:
                                              DismissDirection.endToStart,

                                          // Remove this product from the list
                                          // In production enviroment, you may want to send some request to delete it on server side
                                          onDismissed: (_) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              sets.removeAt(Index1);
                                            });
                                          },
                                          // ignore: sort_child_properties_last
                                          child: Card(
                                              elevation: 0,
                                              child: Padding(
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                                                  child: ListTile(
                                                    title: Text(
                                                      " ",
                                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 10,
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.bold,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    subtitle: Row(
                                                      children: [
                                                        Expanded(
                                                          child: Text(" "),
                                                        ),
                                                        Expanded(
                                                          child: TextField(
                                                            decoration:
                                                                decoratedField,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        Expanded(
                                                          child: TextField(
                                                            decoration:
                                                                decoratedField,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        Expanded(
                                                          child: TextField(
                                                            decoration:
                                                                decoratedField,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ))),
                                          background: Container(
                                              color: Colors.red,
                                              margin:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                horizontal: 15,
                                              ),
                                              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                              child: const Text(
                                                "Delete",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                ),
                                              )));
                                    }),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: ElevatedButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        sets.add('sets-test');
                                        setState(() {});
                                      },
                                      child: const Text('+ Add Set')),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: 5),
                              ],
                              leading: IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.close,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  litems.removeAt(Index);
                                  setState(() {});
                                },
                              ),
                            )));
                  })),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                litems.add("new");
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: const Text('Add Exercises')),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                createUser(user1, "5");
                exercise.setExerciseTotals();
                //saveExercise(exercise);
                final workout = Workout([exercise, exercise1], "Det gik fint",
                    "10", 60, "type", "name", true, 0, 0, 0);
                //workout.setWorkoutTotals();
                saveWorkout(workout, userID);
              },
              child: const Text('pop')),

          bottomSection,
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Comment: could you include decoratedField code too?

Comment: @eamirho3ein  Should be added now.

Answer (score 0):

You are not copy the item, you logic is that add new Item with `null` value, change `decoratedField` to this:

```
final decoratedField = InputDecoration(
    filled: false,
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
    ),
    hintText: "0",
  );
```

Comment: @JesperEgsgaardNielsen was it what you want?